# Acceleration equation

Tags: java, game-physics, equation

I'm making a game in which an object needs to accelerate and decelerate in a certain way.

I have 5 variables:

1. `velX` (current x velocity),
2. `velY` (current y velocity),
3. `desiredVelX` (desired velX value),
4. `desiredVelY` (desired velY value), and
5. `accelTime` (how fast the object accelerates).

Basically, I want an equation that can accelerate `valX` to `desiredValX` when `desiredValX = 10`, `0`, and `-10` when called 128 times a second. And an identical equation for the Y based variables.

I really have no idea how to generate equations for problems like these so some insight into that would be appreciated too.

Here's my current code:

```
public class Player {

private double x;
private double y;
private double velX;
private double velY;
private double desiredVelX;
private double desiredVelY;
private double accelTime = 128 / 2; //Half second to accelerate fully


public Player(double x, double y, Game g)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void tick()
{
    if(velX!=desiredVelX){
        *Equation*
    }

    if(velY!=desiredVelY){
        *Equation*
    }

    x+=velX;
    y+=velY;
}

public void accel(boolean d, double speed){
    if(d){desiredVelX = speed;}
    else{desiredVelY = speed;}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you already answered this but let me just suggest a small change. Try having a variable called acceleration and adding it every frame.

So when you first start accelerating,

```
acceleration = (desiredVelX - velX)/accelTime
```

Then in the loop

```
velX = max(min(velX + acceleration, desiredVelX), 0)
```

This will give you a constant acceleration then stop accelerating after you reach max. The min and max calls ensure you don't go past your limits. Later if you decide to increase your maximum velocity it will easily handle that without you needing to come up with a new acceleration constant for every max speed.

---

**Realistic Physics based on force and weight**

In the real world, acceleration is limited by force and weight. In a car, the engine puts out F force and weighs W. The acceleration of this car is then F / W.

Depending on your game you might have other objects that need to change velocities. Some might be heavier or larger than others or have more power than others.

```
force = 5 # Your force here
acceleration = force / weight
```

Then plug that into the other equation and now you have different acceleration based on the weight of the objects you're acceleration.

Basing your speed and acceleration on real physics will help when trying to implement explosions, gravity bombs, floating platforms, bullet kickback, etc. Realistic physics aren't always desirable so you might not want this, but I thought I'd suggest it anyway.

Comment: Fine approach, just note that the `max min` combo won't work as is for "negative speeds" -- for those it needs a swap: `min max` (without swapping the bounds).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've realized that the equation: `velX += (desiredVelX - velX)/accelTime` will work just fine for my purposes.